# Trivial question regarding a statement about union of events

Tags: probability

I would very much appreciate if someone could shed some light on this statement.
My Probability and statistics book says that the event $A\cup B$ can be written as $A + \overline{A}B$, in other words :
$$ A\cup B = A + \overline{A}B $$

How can I get to the right hand side of the equation ?

Comment: What does "A+ B" mean for A and B sets?

Comment: "A+B" means that the event (A+B) happened whenever A happened or B happened or both at the same time.

Comment: For sets , it basically means union.

Comment: That's what I would have thought but the left side of the equation is "$A\cup B$".  Why use two different notations for the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you treat an event $A$ as if it were a random variable $1_A$ taking the value $1$ on $A$ and $0$ off $A$, then since
$$
1_{A\cup B}=1_A+(1_{A\cup B}-1_A)=1_A+1_{B\setminus A}=1_A+1_{B\cap A^c}=1_A+1_{A^c}\cdot 1_{B}
$$
we get one interpretation of your equation.

Comment: So does this imply that , $A\cup B - A = B\cap \overline{A}$ , if how so ?

Comment: Yes it is a basic set theory observation that $(A\cup B)\setminus A=B\cap A^c$. Indeed, the reason why is that $(A\cup B)\setminus A=B\setminus A$, and $x\in B\setminus A$ means that $x$ is in $B$ but not $A$, or in other words, $x$ is in $B$ and in $A^c$.